# How to make round bottom in css using clip path/border-radius

Tags: html, css

I have a **background image** with **dark overlay** and I have tried to make round bottom using `border-radius` but because of the dark overlay outside the round circle has a dark overlay  so i tried using clip path but i couldnt do it so please help me. [image]

```
header{
    height: 70vh;
    background: url("../image/background1.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30%;    
}
```

Comment: can you show us also the overlap css and html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Using Overflow Hidden

```css
overflow:hidden;
```

[Overflow MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

using clip path:

```
-webkit-clip-path: circle(60.0% at 50% 10%);
clip-path: circle(50.0% at 50% 50%);
```

using border-radius:

```
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.banner-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556228720-d7519e2b88df?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1534&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(70% at 50% 0);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="banner-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <p>Hi! I'm </p>
        <h1>Frontend Developer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope the solution will help. For reference you can go through the link below https://codepen.io/clairebones/full/dopzvv